# What does unique means in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to understand the unique predicate:

for example:

```
unique([H|T],[H|TU]) :- delete(T,E,TN), unique(TN,TU).

delete(T,E,TN) is true if a list TN is identical to a list T
```

after removing all occurrences of an element E.

```
 delete([H|T],H,TN) :- delete(T,H,TN).
 delete([H|T],E,[H|TN]) :- \+ H=E, delete(T,E,TN).
 delete([],_,[]).



unique(['a','b','a','c'],X).

 X = [a, b, c]   <- Enter was pressed

 Yes
```

So it comparing two lists
T = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 't']
TN =['a', 'b', 'd']

removes the occurrences of common elements

This is the entire code:

```
 % delete(L,E,LN) is true if a list LN is identical to a list L
 % after removing all occurences of an element E.
 delete([H|T],H,TN) :- delete(T,H,TN).
 delete([H|T],E,[H|TN]) :- \+ H=E, delete(T,E,TN).
 delete([],_,[]).

 % unique(L,LN) is true if a list LN is identical to a list L
 % without all repeated elements.
 unique([H|T],[H|TU]) :- delete(T,E,TN), unique(TN,TU).
 unique([],[]).
```

please guide here 
thanks a lot

Comment: What is E in delete(T,E,TN)??

Comment: so element E is a letter alphabet

Comment: What letter ? it is not instantiated,  and also unique(['a','b','a','c'],X). returns false and not X=[a,b,c].

Comment: Please remember to use fully reproducible examples including all data necessary to reproduce.

Comment: I have added the whole prolog program just now please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to change
`unique([H|T],[H|TU]) :- delete(T,E,TN), unique(TN,TU).`
 to:
 `unique([H|T],[H|TU]) :- delete(T,H,TN), unique(TN,TU).`

What unique predicate does is to delete element duplicates in the list and keep only the first occurrence. But your predicate fails because you don't handle the case of empty list so if you add the clause:

```
unique([],[]).
```

It works fine:

```
?- unique([a,b,a,c],X).
X = [a, b, c].
```

In this example it calls `unique([a,b,a,c],X)`. which calls `delete([b,a,c],a,TN)` and TN becomes `[b,c]` , calls `unique([b,c],TU)`  and finally returns `[a|TU]`.
TU is found recursively with the same way by calling:`unique([b,c],TU)`
which returns `TU=[b|TU2]` where TU2 given recursively by calling: `unique([c],TU2)` which returns `[c]`.

Comment: You can skip all `'`s